# Pin to start a shortcut on Windows 8 programmatically

Tags: vbscript, windows-8, installshield-2011

I have created an Installer using Installshield 2011. This Installer creates a shortcut in StartMenu-->Programs and it also has runs a vbscript during installation. This VB Script creates another shortcut in StartMenu-->Programs.

The problem is that the shortcut created by Installshield gets automatically "pinned to Start" and hence appear as a tile on metro UI on windows 8, but the shortcut created by VBScript is "NOT pinned to start" and is visible only after clicking on "All Apps" on the Metro UI Desktop.

What can I change in the VBScript so that the shortcut is pinned to start. Is there any API Which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 8 here, so I'm not sure if this will work, but it won't hurt to give it a try:

```
Set sa   = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fldr = sa.NameSpace("C:\PATH\TO\SHORTCUT\FOLDER")
Set lnk  = fldr.ParseName("SHORTCUT.lnk")
For Each verb In lnk.Verbs
  If verb.Name = "Pin to Tas&kbar" Then verb.DoIt()
Next
```