# Pin tile to selected position on Startscreen (programmatically) Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am searching a solution to pin an installed app or desktop application to the windows 8 startscreen.

1. I have figured out to do this like it is described in [this post before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455244/pin-to-start-a-shortcut-on-windows-8-programmatically)
2. There has also been a long disscusion about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994978/how-to-place-a-tile-on-the-windows-8-start-screen-programmatically/17995012?noredirect=1#comment26960256_17995012)

But there was no answer to my question:

**How can I pin a new tile to a selected position on the startscreen?**

If I install a new app/application windows 8 pins the new application at the end of the Startscreen. (windows 8.1 does not)
But if I want to **place the tile** f.e. in the **second group** on **third position**, there is possibilty to do this.

I am in an enterprise environment and I know tools which can provide [this out-of-the-box](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/adminstudio.htm). So there **must** be a way to do this programmatically, but with all my effort I can find a way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a tile on the windows 8 start screen programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994978/how-to-place-a-tile-on-the-windows-8-start-screen-programmatically)

Comment: @JonB - If you had read the post you have linked to, you will see that I asked this question. Also the second point in my post is this post which you thought of being a dublicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible, you can't control where tile will be pinned on start screen.

Comment: That was not the answer i hoped for. But I think it is the only answer :(